# Webpack externals should not be imported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

My app contains different modules, `moduleA`, `moduleB` and `moduleC`. These will be included as `dependencies` in `package.json` of my App.

All of these components contain some common scripts, `react`, `react-dom`, `lodash`, etc.

What is the `webpack` config to build these modules SEPARATELY and then require them in my app? I'm very confused with `webpack` doc.

***Attempt 1: using externals***

I defined a `common` module with `index.js` containg:

```
require('react');
require('react-dom');
require('redux');
require('react-redux');
require('moment');
require('lodash');
```

Then the config file exposed these:

```
module: {
        loaders: [{
                test: require.resolve("react"),
                loader: "expose?React"
            },
            ...
```

This `common.js` is then included before any other file. Then inside each module, using `externals` I have:

```
externals: {
    "react": "React",
    "react-dom": "ReactDom",
    ...
},
```

**Problem**

If I use `import React from 'react'` in any of my modules, a new instance of `react` is imported, causing invariance problem and eventual [addComponentAsRefTo](https://gist.github.com/jimfb/4faa6cbfb1ef476bd105) error.

However, I can perfectly use `React` as it is globally available.

**Attempt 2: CommonsChunkPlugin**

Still include `common.js` from the top. But this time for each module, use `vendors`:

```
entry: {
    "app": "./src/myentry.jsx",
    "vendor": ["react", "react-dom"]
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("vendor", "vendor.js", Infinity)
]
```

***Problem***

Each module creates its own vendor file. How do I then combine all vendor files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two approaches:

1) load react/react-dom from a CDN, and your bundle separately:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

This way, you should not import react (it's already loaded and exposed globally). `ReactDOM.render`, for instance, should work just fine. If you import, you are going to load into your bundle another instance of React (from ./node_modules), which will throw an error and increase your bundle size.

2) the second option (which I use) is to configure webpack to create a common/vendor bundle:

```
entry: {
    "app: "./src/myentry.jsx",
    "vendor": ["react", "react-dom"]
},

output: {
    filename: "[name].js"
},

plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("vendor", "vendor.js", Infinity)
]
```

Webpack will correctly separate the codes and generate both `app.js` and `vendor.js`. Then you should just load them on your page:

```
<script src="vendor.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if I have different modules, each hosted on a different repo? Then the main app will include these modules as dependency and builds the main app. How do I separate the common modules (React, ReactDOM, ...) and then in each module use them correctly?

Comment: If you use the **CommonsChunkPlugin** option above, you can specify which modules you want to include in your vendor/common bundle in the **entry** option (I have a project that my common bundle is **["react", "react-dom", "react-addons-css-transition-group", "react-redux"]**). In your modules, you just import normally, no difference.  Webpack docs aren't so clear, buy try checking this [link](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html). It might help.

Comment: How are the vendors of different modules combined then?! Each module is built and compiled separately and is then added as a dependency to the main app.

Comment: Multiple entry point is not what you're looking for?

`entry: {
       "page1": "./src/page1.jsx", // bundle for the page1
       "page2": "./src/page2.jsx", // bundle for the page2,
       "page3": "./src/page3.jsx", // bundle for the page1
 "vendor": ["react", "react-dom"]
}`

This will create multiple bundles (page1, page2, page3, vendor). Then on page1 you should load bundle+page1. At page2, bundle+page2. Dont know if I understood your needs correctly.

Comment: Well, no. If I include multiple different components into my main app, they all should use the same react library and other shared libraries. Not that each should pull its own.

Comment: No, if I include multiple reference to react, things will fail!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use a remote or cdn `react react-dom etc` files, why you require them in your common.js. as your know CMD, if your require in your common.js file

```
require('react');
require('react-dom');
require('redux');
require('react-redux');
require('moment');
require('lodash');
```

then the variable `React, ReactDom` is not a golbal variable. your cann't visit it in your other files.
you can do it like this:

```
window.React = require('react');
window.ReactDom = require('react-dom');
window.Redux = require('redux');
window.ReactRedux = require('react-redux');
window.monment = require('moment');
window.lodash = require('lodash');
```

and insert such a srcript tag into your html `<srcipt src="/common.bunld.js">`
just make sure `common.js` is in your webpack entry.

Comment: No, you are misunderstanding me. My problem is that they are defined globally. Which is fine; so I can just use `React` without `require('react')` first. If, however, I do `require('react')`, a new instance of React is imported, and then I get other issues.